# Alfine 8 gear crunch

Tags: internally-geared-hub

Occasionally under load when taking off on the flat, I would get a crunch, then it runs smoothly.

After reading the other post I had tightened the wheel nuts but this has not fixed the issue. I have checked the yellow lines align also. It occurs in variety of gears. The bike was only 1 week old before it happened and it was next day after ride in rain.

I live in NZ and bought the bike in Australia, so taking back to vendor is not a option. For interests sake it's a focus planet belt drive.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Darin. Lots of businesses in NZ can help with your [Alfine hub](https://www.google.com.au/?q=Alfine+8+gear+NZ). Maybe the place you bought from has a branch there too. You could also ring the Australian business, and see if they recommend anyone.

Comment: Has it been that way ever since you got it? Did you get it new?

Comment: If its one week old, don't mess up your warranty.   Depending on what bike shop, they may have outlets in New Zealand, or a bike shop may be able to pro-charge them for work at shop rates.  What NZ city are you in and from which bike shop in AU did you buy the bike?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of 'crunch' you experience, but I have a possibly similar behavior of my Alfine 11 hub when I switch gears and I apply some force on the pedals.

Resting my foot on the pedal while standing and shifting is enough for the internal gears to not complete the shift, when I start pedaling, the gears engage in the speed I shifted giving a noticeable crunching noise.

Answer (score 1):

The crunchiness appears to be a well-known failure mode of the Shimano internal geared hubs. If your hub is under warranty, I wouldn't hesitate to return it and get a new one.

The warranty is a Shimano warranty, so any bike shop that handles Shimano should be able to process it for you.